# What's wrong with alpha blend?

Tags: transparency

Alpha blend seems to result in the entire mesh being weirdly semi-transparent or something. [image]

In this object only the glass bottle has transparency yet the other components have this effect as well even though they have no transparency. I'm using a png file with a black and white mask applied to the basecolor.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Stop using the absolutely worst designed image encoding format known to humankind; PNG. It’s complete garbage, and does not belong in an imaging pipeline. Blender should wake up and remove it from being default, giving it an air of validity. It is pure garbage.

Comment: Hello :). Maybe your UV map is overlapping? Do you use a second material for the non-transparent parts? You can also [share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: I think you need to disable "show backfaces" in the same panel where you enabled the alpha blend

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3zJe5R4n" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3zJe5R4n/)

Comment: here is the file

Comment: I dont think its the png or the show backfaces or the uv overlapping. checked all those setting out. The main issue is that the ribbon and the flower have this weird clipping/transparent effect? they are supposed to be opaque. Rendering this in cycles somehow resolved the issue

Comment: But my objective is to export this to a 3d web AR platform https://awe.media/ which is dependent on the alpha modes in blender. Somehow the alpha blend issue is replicated there.